# Encryption using public/private keys between mobile client and server PHP

Tags: php, android, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key

**Case 1:Encrypted Data from client to Server**

Need to create a public/private key in server.Public key provided to client.The client encrypts it with public key.The server decrypts it using the private key that was generated.

**Case2: But what about the case when the data from server is sent to the 
client side.??**

That  data should also be encrypted.Does the same public/private that was created for case 1 work or new key should be generated?can anybody please explain case2 for my requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just use HTTPS for that?

Comment: We are already using HTTPS. The clients want more security underneath the protocol in the data level.I have been browsing all day long for the above topic.But nothing seemed promising till now.Can you please help?

Comment: https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption#crypto-seal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use public / private key encryption in any direction.

So your client can encrypt with public key, then the server can decrypt with private key.
If your server encrypts with private key, the client can decrypt with public key.

Comment: Thanks Rene for your answer.So should I create one more pair for the case 2.That means for a secure two way communication between client and server we need a pair of both public and private key?

Comment: No I wouldn't, because this will end up in only one key pair for the backward way. Better is to create a keypair for every client on server side. Keep the private part private and send the public key to the client. Because private key encryption is also possible like public key encryption and vice versa!

Comment: But rene using the above technique the client will encrypt using the public key and the server will decrypt using the private key which only the server knows.But what to do when the server needs to encrypt the data and send it to client as a response.I need  that too to be secured

Comment: The server can encrypt data for a client with his private key!!!! and the client can decrypt with the public key then!!!

Comment: *"If your server encrypts with private key, the client can decrypt with public key."* - No. No. No. This doesn't provide confidentiality (as in encryption), but only authenticity (as in digital signature), but it only works if the data that is signed is transmitted along side it and the client verifies that the signature was correct using the verification key (public key).

Answer (score 3):

As outlined in this [white paper on secure data encryption](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption#crypto-seal) and its supporting material:

1. Use HTTPS.
2. For a second layer of authenticated encryption, use [libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/) (a modern, cross-platfrom cryptography library) with pinned public keys.

#### PHP Example

**Key Generation**

```
$bob_box_kp = \Sodium\crypto_box_keypair();
$bob_box_secretkey = \Sodium\crypto_box_secretkey($bob_box_kp);
$bob_box_publickey = \Sodium\crypto_box_publickey($bob_box_kp);
```

**Encryption**

```
$anonymous_message_to_bob = \Sodium\crypto_box_seal(
    $message,
    $bob_box_publickey
);
```

**Decryption**

```
$decrypted_message = \Sodium\crypto_box_seal_open(
    $anonymous_message_to_bob,
    $bob_box_kp
);
if ($decrypted_message === false) {
    // You have the wrong keypair or the message was tampered with.
}
```

#### Android Example (using [Libstodium](https://github.com/ArteMisc/libstodium))

**Key Generation**

```
byte[] secret_key = new byte[Box.SECRETKEYBYTES];
byte[] public_key = new byte[Box.PUBLICKEYBYTES];
Box.keypair(public_key, secret_key);
```

**Encryption**

```
Box.seal(
    ciphertextByteArray, // Output goes here
    plaintextByteArray,  // Your message
    public_key
);
```

**Decryption**

```
Box.sealOpen(
    plaintextOutputByteArray, // Decrypted data goes here
    ciphertextByteArray,      // Encrypted message received over the wire
    public_key,
    secret_key
);
```